# Backbone: create model and put the id from server in the success

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to get the id of a saved model

```
    var newBookmark = bookmarks.create(values,{
        success:function(){
            console.log('Successfuly saved')
            console.log(idOfThisModel) //need id from the server here
            this.close()
        },
        error: function(){console.log('error, didnt save')},
    })
```

How can I get the id of the model into the success method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it as function param:

```
success:function( idOfThisModel ){
```

Answer (score 1):

From Backbone.js `fetch` [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)

> Accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which are passed (model, response, options) and (model, xhr, options) as arguments, respectively.

So you just need to use the arguments passed to your callbacks

```
success: function(model, resp, opts) {
  var id = model[whateverYourIdAttributeIs];
  // ... etc
}
```